# Who is eligible to play in the 2017 FIDE Asian Zonal 3.3 in Tagaytay, Philippines?

Tags: tournament

I'm struggling to find information on this chess tournament.  It's listed on FIDE's website ([link](https://www.fide.com/index.php?option=com_fidecalendar&view=fidecalendar&ny=2017)):

[image: Asian Zonal 3.3, Tagaytay, Philippines, 24 Feb 2017 to 6 Mar 2016]

I'd be interested in playing in this tournament, but my federation is Australia and I don't know if I'm eligible.

*Question*: Who is eligible to play in the 2017 FIDE Asian Zonal 3.3 in Tagaytay, Philippines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tournament is for federations in zone 3.3 (basically SE-Asia and Japan). Australia is in zone 3.6. So you could only play at the Asian zonal 3.6 in Auckland.

Comment: Thank you.  (I'm thinking of playing in the New Zealand one, but the Philippines sounded more tempting.  I don't really understand the zonal system.)

Comment: Having had a look at the participants of the 2015 zonal for zone 3.6, I was surprised to see quite some low rated players (down to ratings of 1300 and unrated players). Also there were quite a few more players from Australia than just 5. That's why I removed all that text above and only left what is definitely true, that you can only play in zonal 3.6.